# Python equivalent of MATLAB function findchangepts

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I need a python equivalent of the MATLAB command [findchangepts](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findchangepts.html) . I am unable to find one yet. Essentially I want to find K abrupt changes in my time series.

I am able to use the matlab command but unable to find an equivalent function in python. Any help/pointers to existing libraries will be very helpful. I am not proficient in the optimization modules of scipy and thus would prefer an existing python package.

Thanks.

Comment: Might I ask why am I being downvoted? This question has not been asked before and I am unable to find anything.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I found https://github.com/viveksck/changepoint, but it looks like it uses R behind the hood, and doesn't seem maintained anymore. Use at your own risks ;)

Comment: Note that `findchangepts` is open-source. So if you have access to MATLAB you can just see how it works and try to replicate in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the answer might help:

I have both MATLAB and Python on my computer. I was able to use MATLAB bindings for python to use findchangepts in my python code.

Source for bindings : [MATLAB API for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html)

Comment: For me MATLAB is too expensive and it gives me no features in addition to my open source tool collection I use. However good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use Matlab under the hood there is e.g. [ruptures](https://pypi.org/project/ruptures/) which implements change point detection ([docs](http://ctruong.perso.math.cnrs.fr/ruptures-docs/build/html/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

`ruptures` is definitely worth a try and it includes the same algorithm as used in `findchangepts`. But if anybody needs a Bayesian alternative, one possible tool in Python is the `BEAST` method my team developed, which is available at https://pypi.org/project/Rbeast/. Unlike classical algorithms such as `findchangepts` or `ruptures`, `BEAST` tells not just when the changepoints occur but also quantifies the probability of changepoint occurrence. See below for a quick illustration.